# PHP imap move and delete messages

Tags: php, imap

im using this https://github.com/SSilence/php-imap-client library to work with imap. Trying use methods moveMessages and deleteMessages, after execute i get fatal errors "$id does not exist" for all messages, but moveMessage work fine.

My code:

```
if ($action == "moveToArchive"){
    $imap->moveMessages($_POST['id'], 'INBOX.Archive');
}
```

Php imap client code:

```
public function moveMessages($ids, $target)
{
    if (imap_mail_move($this->imap, implode(",", $ids), $target, CP_UID) === false)
        return false;
    return imap_expunge($this->imap);
}
```

My function for open messages with ajax:

```
if ($action == "getMessage"){
    if (!file_exists('attachments/'.$_SESSION["username"].'')) {
        mkdir('attachments/'.$_SESSION["username"].'', 0777, true);
    }

    $imap->setFlagMessage($id, "\\Seen");
    $message = $imap->getMessage($id);
    $unixTimestamp=strtotime($message->header->date);

    if(isset($message->message->html)){
        $messageBody = $message->message->html->body;
    } else {
        $messageBody = $message->message->plain;
    }
    foreach($message->header->details->reply_to as $reply) {
        $reply_all = $reply->mailbox.'@'.$reply->host.', ';
    }

    echo '<div class="flex-row d-flex mail" data-id="'.$message->header->uid.'">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/45x45" alt="avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="from">
                <div class="name">'.$message->header->from.'</div>
                <div class="address">&lt;'.$message->header->details->from[0]->mailbox.'@'.$message->header->details->from[0]->host.'&gt;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="date flex-fill text-right">'.date("F j, Y, g:i A", $unixTimestamp).'</div>
          </div>
          <div class="recipient mb-5"><strong>To:</strong> '.$message->header->to.'</div>
          <div class="message-body">'.$messageBody.'</div>
        ';
    if(!empty($message->attachments)) {
        echo '<div class="attachments card mt-3 bg-secondary"><div class="card-header text-white">Attachments</div><div class="card-body">';
        foreach($message->attachments as $attachment){
            $name = $attachment->name;
            $contents = $attachment->body;
            file_put_contents('attachments/'.$_SESSION["username"].'/'.$name, $contents);
            echo '<a class="btn btn-light mr-2" href="attachments/'.$_SESSION["username"].'/'.$name.'" target="_blank">'.$name.'</a>';
            /*if ($attachment->info->subtype == 'JPG') {
                echo '<img class="img-fluid" src="attachments/'.$_SESSION["username"].'/'.$name.'" alt="">';
            }*/
        }
        echo '</div></div>';
    }
    echo '
          <div class="mt-3 no-print">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark reply" data-reply="'.$message->header->details->reply_to[0]->mailbox.'@'.$message->header->details->reply_to[0]->host.'"><i class="icon-reply mr-1"></i>Reply</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark reply-all" data-reply-all="'.$reply_all.'"><i class="icon-reply mr-1"></i>Reply all</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark forward" data-forward="'.$message->header->details->reply_to[0]->mailbox.'@'.$message->header->details->reply_to[0]->host.'"><i class="icon-forward mr-1"></i>Forward</button>
          </div>
          <div class="my-3 no-print reply-container" style="display:none;">
            <div class="compose-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div class="compose-title text-white"></div>
            </div>
            <form class="reply-form position-relative">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sendMail">
                <div class="form-group m-0">  
                    <input type="text" name="to" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="To:">
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group m-0">
                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" value="'.$message->header->subject.'" placeholder="Subject:">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group m-0">
                    <textarea name="message" class="form-control reply-editor"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="compose-footer mt-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                    <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-link text-dark"><i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        ';
}
```

Any ideas why my messages do not open after execute method? Roundcube and Rainloop open all messages.

Comment: doesn't expunge change all of the id's ?, also rainloop doesn't use php imap (not extensively anyway), not sure for roundcube

Comment: I have CP_UID flag in function after run imap_expunge($this->imap), need change all id's after move or delete messages? Little example?

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing UIDs and sequence numbers.

Comment: UID not sequence number for CP_UID? Im use only UID everywhere